# PyQt/QListWidget: how to edit data rather than display text?

Tags: pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have a dictionary of tuple:name pairs.  I display the names in a QListWidget, but I retrieve and work with the tuples -- the names are strictly for display purposes.  The setFlags line in the code below allows me to edit the display names, but what I actually want to be able to do is edit the tuple data.  I tried adding the Qt.EditRole bit, but ended up with nothing but blank lines in the QListWidget for my trouble.  How can I let the user edit the tuple data (via user interface) and then have my code query the dictionary to update the display name?

```
for tuple in tuples:
    name = dict[tuple]
    this_item = QListWidgetItem(name)
    this_item.setData(Qt.UserRole,tuple)
#   this_item.setData(Qt.EditRole, tuple)
    this_item.setFlags(this_item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    self.addItem(this_item)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to edit the tuple-data through the user interface?

Comment: @ekhumoro: exactly.  Maybe ideally in a table view, with names and tuples side-by-side.

Comment: Sounds like you have answered your own question...

Comment: @ekhumoro:  I suppose I did (though I still need to figure out what Qt.EditRole is supposed to be about).  Anyway, I posted the code I came up with to move forward with my side-by-side editor approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit the data behind the name, I'll add a method within my QListWidget that creates a custom editing environment:

```
def edit_items(self):
    dialog = MyQDialog(self.parent())
    table = QTableWidget(self.count(),2,dialog)
    for row in range(0, self.count()):
        spec = repr(self.item(row).data(32).toPyObject())
        name = self.item(row).text()
        spec_item = QTableWidgetItem(spec)
        name_item = QTableWidgetItem(name)
        table.setItem(row,0,name_item)
        table.setItem(row,1,spec_item)
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addStrut(550)
    layout.addWidget(table)
    dialog.setLayout(layout)
    dialog.show()
```

and then go from there.